# Pasting into redactor with Arabic

Tags: localization, editor

IS there a way of getting redactor to accept text pasted from arabic in a right to left flow? Should this be solved with custom style for editor based on locale? (Am already doing RTL direction in front end based on locale)

Comment: Is this on the front-end of the site? This should already be happening in the control panel. If so, sounds like you're looking for: https://imperavi.com/redactor/examples/text-direction/

Comment: Thanks and yes thats what I want - but where does one put this js?

Comment: When you're instantiating your Redactor instance like in the example?

Comment: This is the CPanel editing content not the front end. So its not already happening in the rich text field editing in the control panel - which it should?

Comment: Ohh... it will only happen if you're currently viewing the CP in a RTL based language like Arabic.

Comment: So it is happening in arabic but only on first load of new page - the english copy is RTL. As soon as I paste arabic from google translate it goes LTR....

Comment: What is weird is toggling HTML button - the raw html is RTL....

Comment: If you think you've found a bug, send in steps to reproduce to support@craftcms.com. I'm able to paste Google Translate Arabic text into a Rich Text field viewing the CP in Arabic and it's RTL as expected.

Comment: Email/Bug submitted. For reference made a video demo of issue: http://screencast.com/t/Ilem7uqI

Comment: The bug is what if you're viewing the CP in English, but editing an Arabic entry, then the Rich Text field (and Plain Text for that matter) should display in RTL. Right now it is based on the locale you're viewing the CP in. We plan to have this fixed in Craft 3.

Comment: ANy update on this bug? My solution has stopped working. The redactor interface shows arabic lef-to-right only despite injected css styles

Answer (score 1):

Update: temp fix
as per comments below i fixed with js plugin https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpjs

Rough and ready hack to only run extra js when editing arabic entry.
On CpjsPlugin.php I edited the bottom:

```
 private function _renderJs()
 {
    $settings = $this->getSettings();
    if (trim($settings->jsFile)) {
        $filepath = craft()->config->parseEnvironmentString($settings->jsFile);
        if ($hash = @sha1_file($filepath)) {
            craft()->templates->includeJsFile($filepath.'?e='.$hash);
        } else {
            craft()->templates->includeJsFile($filepath);
        }
    }
    //joomkit hack for arabic redactor  fix
    $lang =  $this->_getCurrentLocale();
    //only add extra js if arabic is set in url
    if($lang == "ar"){ 
        craft()->templates->includeJs($settings->additionalJs);
    }    
}

private function _getCurrentLocale() {

    $segments = craft()->request->segments;
    $lastSegment = end($segments);

    return $lastSegment;

}
```

The the extra js settings;

```
$(function()
{
$('.redactor-editor>*').css({
    direction: 'rtl',
    float: 'right'
});
$('.input #title').css({
    direction: 'rtl',
    float: 'right'
});
```

});

this will help arabic translators start translating hopefully

Comment: What solution are you using at the moment for this? Did the craft cpjs plugin still work?